# Python 3: Persist strings without b'

Tags: string, python-3.x, csv

I am confused. This [talk](https://pyvideo.org/pycon-us-2012/pragmatic-unicode-or-how-do-i-stop-the-pain.html) explains, that you should only use unicode-strings in your code. When strings leave your code, you should turn them into bytes. I did this for a csv file:

```
import csv

with open('keywords.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter='\t', quotechar='\"')
    for (p, keywords) in ml_data:
        writer.writerow([p.encode("utf-8"), ', '.join(keywords).encode("utf-8")])
```

This leads to an annoying effect, where `b'` is added in front of every string, this didn't happen for me in python 2.7. When not encoding the strings before writing them into the csv file, the `b'` is not there, but don't I need to turn them into bytes when persisting? How do I write bytes into a file without this `b'` annoyance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stop trying to encode the individual strings, instead you should specify the encoding for the entire file:

```
import csv

with open('keywords.csv', 'w', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter='\t', quotechar='\"')
    for (p, keywords) in ml_data:
        writer.writerow([p, ', '.join(keywords)])
```

The reason your code goes wrong is that `writerow` is expecting you to give it strings but you're passing bytes so it uses the `repr()` of the bytes which has the extra `b'...'` around it. If you pass it strings but use the `encoding` parameter when you open the file then the strings will be encoded correctly for you.

See the [`csv` documentation examples](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#examples). One of these shows you how to set the encoding.

Comment: Okay thanks. I bet it worked in python 2.7, because there are actually byte strings, which are considered strings. In python 3.x there are only unicode strings, right?